# Jnetpcap not finding ALL devices

Tags: java, pcap, jnetpcap

I am using JnetPcap on my Wifi, I want it to find devices connected to my internet like my mobile phone and listen for data, I am using the current method to find devices:

```java
    private static List<PcapIf> getDevices() {
        List<PcapIf> devices = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();

        int x = Pcap.findAllDevs(devices, err);

        if (x == Pcap.NOT_OK || devices.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + err.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return devices;
    }
```

but the issue is its not finding my mobile phone (which is connected to the internet).